# White Square in SFML, Sprite and texture stored in different objects

Tags: c++, oop, graphics, sfml

I'm experiencing the [white square problem](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem) in SFML. I'm working on a game that uses a tiled map. A `Game` class will load the tile set as a sf::Texture from a file and then a getTileById function in `Game` will "Cut" out the appropriate tile from the tileset texture. Eg.

```
sf::Sprite GameScreen::getSpriteByPos(int pos, sf::Texture texture, int tileSize) {
    sf::IntRect subRect;
    subRect.left = (pos-1)*tileSize;
    subRect.top = (pos-1)*tileSize;
    subRect.width = tileSize;
    subRect.height = tileSize;

    sf::Sprite tileSprite(texture, subRect);
    return tileSprite;
}
```

The sprite will then be passed into a Tile object, which will then set its sprite_ attribute to it. Eg.

```
void Tile::setSprite(sf::Sprite sprite) {
    sprite_ = sprite;
}
```

The `Game` object will load all tiles in this way and store them all in a vector. To draw them, it will loop through the vector and call the `Tile::draw(sf::RenderWindow&)` method on each one of them (Passing in the RenderWindow to be drawn to). This method takes an sf::RenderWindow and the tile simply calls the `sf::RenderWindow::draw(sf::Sprite)` on the RenderWindow with its `sprite_` attribute. Eg.

```
void Tile::draw(sf::RenderWindow &window){
    window.draw(sprite_);
    return;
}
```

I'd like to do drawing this way because the `Tile::draw` method is inherited from a `Drawable` class, so that all objects that are drawable can inherit from Drawable and implement their drawing method in a way that suits them, something that will be necessary in my project. The sprite is being drawn as a white square though, which strikes me as strange as the tileSet_ attribute has not been destroyed, it is an attribute of the `Game` class and still exists.

Can anybody tell me what is going on here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing your texture "by value". That means you get a copy of your texture inside this function:

```
sf::Sprite GameScreen::getSpriteByPos(int pos, sf::Texture texture, int tileSize) {
    sf::IntRect subRect;
    subRect.left = (pos-1)*tileSize;
    subRect.top = (pos-1)*tileSize;
    subRect.width = tileSize;
    subRect.height = tileSize;

    sf::Sprite tileSprite(texture, subRect);
    return tileSprite;
}
```

But that copy is destroyed when the function ends.

You don't need that copy, so don't make a copy:

```
sf::Sprite GameScreen::getSpriteByPos(int pos, const sf::Texture& texture, int tileSize) {
    sf::IntRect subRect;
    subRect.left = (pos-1)*tileSize;
    subRect.top = (pos-1)*tileSize;
    subRect.width = tileSize;
    subRect.height = tileSize;

    sf::Sprite tileSprite(texture, subRect);
    return tileSprite;
}
```